# how to setup single node cassandra cluster on azure

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

for more than 3 days i am trying to connect single node cassandra cluster setup on azure. i want to connect nodejs script running on my pc to show data from cassandra on azure.

public ip of my azure vm is 52.170.220.106. i will attach firewall settings screenshots. my nodejs script cant connect to 9042 or 9061 same thing with datastax dev center gui.

i open ports by setting up inbound and outbound security rules in azure.

Nodejs Client Code:

```
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
// var dbclient = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['h1', 'h2'], keyspace: 'ks1' });
// var dbclient = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['52.87.181.106'], keyspace: 'movielens_small' });
var dbclient = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['52.170.220.106'], keyspace: 'mydb' });
//ec2-52-87-181-106.compute-1.amazonaws.com
var dbquery = 'SELECT * FROM books limit 1';

try {
  dbclient.execute(dbquery)
   .then(result => console.log('movie name is =  %s', result.rows[0].title));
}
catch(ex){
  console.log(ex.innerErrors);
}
```

cassandra.yaml file content:

```
# Cassandra storage config YAML

# NOTE:
#   See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/StorageConfiguration for
#   full explanations of configuration directives
# /NOTE

# The name of the cluster. This is mainly used to prevent machines in
# one logical cluster from joining another.
cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

# This defines the number of tokens randomly assigned to this node on the ring
# The more tokens, relative to other nodes, the larger the proportion of data
# that this node will store. You probably want all nodes to have the same number
# of tokens assuming they have equal hardware capability.
#
# If you leave this unspecified, Cassandra will use the default of 1 token for legacy compatibility,
# and will use the initial_token as described below.
#
# Specifying initial_token will override this setting on the node's initial start,
# on subsequent starts, this setting will apply even if initial token is set.
#
# If you already have a cluster with 1 token per node, and wish to migrate to
# multiple tokens per node, see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations
num_tokens: 256

# Triggers automatic allocation of num_tokens tokens for this node. The allocation
# algorithm attempts to choose tokens in a way that optimizes replicated load over
# the nodes in the datacenter for the replication strategy used by the specified
# keyspace.
#
# The load assigned to each node will be close to proportional to its number of
# vnodes.
#
# Only supported with the Murmur3Partitioner.
# allocate_tokens_for_keyspace: KEYSPACE

# initial_token allows you to specify tokens manually.  While you can use it with
# vnodes (num_tokens > 1, above) -- in which case you should provide a
# comma-separated list -- it's primarily used when adding nodes to legacy clusters
# that do not have vnodes enabled.
# initial_token:

# See http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HintedHandoff
# May either be "true" or "false" to enable globally
hinted_handoff_enabled: true

# When hinted_handoff_enabled is true, a black list of data centers that will not
# perform hinted handoff
# hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters:
#    - DC1
#    - DC2

# this defines the maximum amount of time a dead host will have hints
# generated.  After it has been dead this long, new hints for it will not be
# created until it has been seen alive and gone down again.
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours

# Maximum throttle in KBs per second, per delivery thread.  This will be
# reduced proportionally to the number of nodes in the cluster.  (If there
# are two nodes in the cluster, each delivery thread will use the maximum
# rate; if there are three, each will throttle to half of the maximum,
# since we expect two nodes to be delivering hints simultaneously.)
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024

# Number of threads with which to deliver hints;
# Consider increasing this number when you have multi-dc deployments, since
# cross-dc handoff tends to be slower
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

# Directory where Cassandra should store hints.
# If not set, the default directory is $CASSANDRA_HOME/data/hints.
# hints_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/hints

# How often hints should be flushed from the internal buffers to disk.
# Will *not* trigger fsync.
hints_flush_period_in_ms: 10000

# Maximum size for a single hints file, in megabytes.
max_hints_file_size_in_mb: 128

# Compression to apply to the hint files. If omitted, hints files
# will be written uncompressed. LZ4, Snappy, and Deflate compressors
# are supported.
#hints_compression:
#   - class_name: LZ4Compressor
#     parameters:
#         -

# Maximum throttle in KBs per second, total. This will be
# reduced proportionally to the number of nodes in the cluster.
batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024

# Authentication backend, implementing IAuthenticator; used to identify users
# as corrupted.
# max_value_size_in_mb: 256

# Back-pressure settings #
# If enabled, the coordinator will apply the back-pressure strategy specified below to each mutation
# sent to replicas, with the aim of reducing pressure on overloaded replicas.
back_pressure_enabled: false
# The back-pressure strategy applied.
# The default implementation, RateBasedBackPressure, takes three arguments:
# high ratio, factor, and flow type, and uses the ratio between incoming mutation responses and outgoing mutation requests.
# If below high ratio, outgoing mutations are rate limited according to the incoming rate decreased by the given factor;
# if above high ratio, the rate limiting is increased by the given factor;
# such factor is usually best configured between 1 and 10, use larger values for a faster recovery
# at the expense of potentially more dropped mutations;
# the rate limiting is applied according to the flow type: if FAST, it's rate limited at the speed of the fastest replica,
# if SLOW at the speed of the slowest one.
# New strategies can be added. Implementors need to implement org.apache.cassandra.net.BackpressureStrategy and
# provide a public constructor accepting a Map<String, Object>.
back_pressure_strategy:
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure
      parameters:
        - high_ratio: 0.90
          factor: 5
          flow: FAST

# Coalescing Strategies #
# Coalescing multiples messages turns out to significantly boost message processing throughput (think doubling or more).
# On bare metal, the floor for packet processing throughput is high enough that many applications won't notice, but in
# virtualized environments, the point at which an application can be bound by network packet processing can be
# surprisingly low compared to the throughput of task processing that is possible inside a VM. It's not that bare metal
# doesn't benefit from coalescing messages, it's that the number of packets a bare metal network interface can process
# is sufficient for many applications such that no load starvation is experienced even without coalescing.
# There are other benefits to coalescing network messages that are harder to isolate with a simple metric like messages
# per second. By coalescing multiple tasks together, a network thread can process multiple messages for the cost of one
# trip to read from a socket, and all the task submission work can be done at the same time reducing context switching
# and increasing cache friendliness of network message processing.
# See CASSANDRA-8692 for details.

# Strategy to use for coalescing messages in OutboundTcpConnection.
# Can be fixed, movingaverage, timehorizon, disabled (default).
# You can also specify a subclass of CoalescingStrategies.CoalescingStrategy by name.
# otc_coalescing_strategy: DISABLED

# How many microseconds to wait for coalescing. For fixed strategy this is the amount of time after the first
# message is received before it will be sent with any accompanying messages. For moving average this is the
# maximum amount of time that will be waited as well as the interval at which messages must arrive on average
# for coalescing to be enabled.
# otc_coalescing_window_us: 200

# Do not try to coalesce messages if we already got that many messages. This should be more than 2 and less than 128.
# otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages: 8

# How many milliseconds to wait between two expiration runs on the backlog (queue) of the OutboundTcpConnection.
# Expiration is done if messages are piling up in the backlog. Droppable messages are expired to free the memory
# taken by expired messages. The interval should be between 0 and 1000, and in most installations the default value
# will be appropriate. A smaller value could potentially expire messages slightly sooner at the expense of more CPU
# time and queue contention while iterating the backlog of messages.
# An interval of 0 disables any wait time, which is the behavior of former Cassandra versions.
#
# otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms: 200
```

[image]

[image]